# Downloading Constantly "/.local/share/kite/current/kite-update"

Tags: networking, upgrade, updates, sharing

I have kite downloading a large amount of data "/home/$$$/.local/share/kite/current/kite-update ".
What is this kite responsible for and why is it always downloading data.
"/home/$$$/.local/share/kite/current/kite-update "

Comment: `man kite;info kite;locate kite;dpkg -l | grep kite` will get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Kite is a code completion tool. It is sometimes bundled with editors like Atom or IDEs like Spyder.

It took me a while to determine that my Linux box was the culprit causing me to go over my 1.5 TB monthly cable internet data limit (my Netgear Orbi router does not provide device data usage). I used *nethogs* to then isolate that *kite-update* was the process doing this.

In fact, *~/.local/share/kite/current/kite-update* was consuming about 1 TB per month from my Ubuntu 21.10 desktop.

You can find more information about kite here: https://help.kite.com/article/86-linux-faq

Comment: Thanks for your clarify

Comment: you like in no longer available! besides is there any safe way to remove kite from ubuntu machines?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same data blow out issue after kite failed to install properly within the forked version of 'Atom' called 'Pulsar'. I removed it by doing the following (from your home dir),

```
$.local/share/kite/current/kite-update uninstall;rm -rf .kite
```